# Characteristic polynomial of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix.

How to calculate  its characteristic polynomial?

I know it should be $X^n$, but I don't know why?

Comment: Do you know about minimal polynomials and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem? Or (if working over the complex numbers) you could argue which possible eigenvalues a nilpotent matrix can have.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The minimal polynomial is of the form $x^k$ for some $k$, because the matrix is nilpotent. Since the minimal polynomial is divisible by all the irreducible polynomials which divide the characteristic polynomial, we see that in fact the only irreducible polynomial which divides the latter is $x$. Thus $\chi_A(x)=x^n$.

Comment: So does that mean for $n \times n$ size matrices, there is only one similarity class of  nilpotent matrices?

Comment: @PythonSage, nope, not at all. The classification is given by the the Jordan canonical form.

Answer (score 24):

If the overlying field is the complex numbers (see Listing's and Mark's comment):

If $A^k=0$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $\bf x$:

$$\eqalign{
A {\bf x}=\lambda {\bf x} &\Rightarrow A^2  {\bf x}= \lambda^2  {\bf x} \cr 
&\Rightarrow  A^3 {\bf x}=\lambda^3  {\bf x}\cr
&\ {\vdots} \cr &\Rightarrow 0=\lambda^{k } {\bf x} \cr &  \Rightarrow \lambda=0}
\ \ \ \raise6pt{\left. {\vphantom{\matrix{1\cr1\cr1\cr1\cr1\cr}}}\right\}}
\raise6pt{\scriptstyle{(k-1)-\text{times}}}
$$

So 0 is the only eigenvalue of $A$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is then $x^n$.

Comment: This answer assumes that you are working over an algebraic closed field.

Comment: @Listing Thanks, I edited the post to reflect this.