# If the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$ has $n$ zero roots, then $A$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove the following statement:

If the characteristic polynomial of matrix  $A$ has $n$ zero roots, then $A$ is nilpotent.

Thank you!

Comment: Is $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88239/characteristic-polynomial-of-a-nilpotent-matrix).

Comment: Have you heard of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the characteristic polynomial has only zero roots, it has the form $\lambda^n = 0$ (or $(-\lambda)^n = 0$, depending on convention).
By the theorem of Cayley-Hamilton, a square matrix $A$ fulfills its own characteristic equation (even if it's not diagonalizable),
therefore $A^n = 0$ (zero matrix), therefore $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Actually I made that, thanks first of all, now, nothing can be said about the index of nilpotenty, right?

Comment: You are right, the index of nilpotency is found in the minimal polynomial, not in the characteristic polynomial

Comment: @17SI.34SA: no, nothing (except of course it is at most n). Note that a matrix is nilpotent if and only if its minimal polynomial is of this form (over a field and a domain, at least, but I assume you are in this situation). Also, consider a matrix, 0 except for 1 on the fist upper diagonal,  compute the sqaure of this matrix and observe you get one 0 except for 1 on second upper diagonal and so on.

Comment: @quid: many thanks.